# Golang token validation error

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, rsa, google-oauth, jwt

I need to validate a google id_token and one step involves to check the token signature.

First I obtain the certificate from: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/certs and extract the modulus (n) and exponent (e) part from the certificate and generate a public key, then I take apart the token (header, payload and digest), after then I send the decoded `header.payload` together with the Google pKey + digest to the rsa function `rsa.VerifyPKCS1v15`.

I am stuck with this verification error: `crypto/rsa: verification error`

Here's the code (I commented part of code which fails with `// validation here fails`):

```
func ValidateIDToken(auth_token string) (err error){    
    res, err := http.Get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/certs")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return err
    }

    certs, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return err
    }

    //get modulus and exponent from the cert
    var goCertificate interface{}

    err = json.Unmarshal(certs, &goCertificate)    
    k := goCertificate.(map[string]interface{})["keys"]
    j := k.([]interface{})
    x := j[1]
    h := x.(map[string]interface{})["n"]
    g := x.(map[string]interface{})["e"]
    e64 := base64.StdEncoding
    //build the google pub key
    nStr := h.(string)
    decN, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(nStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    n := big.NewInt(0)
    n.SetBytes(decN)
    eStr := g.(string)
    decE, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(eStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    var eBytes []byte
    if len(decE) < 8 {
        eBytes = make([]byte, 8-len(decE), 8)
        eBytes = append(eBytes, decE...)
    } else {
        eBytes = decE
    }

    eReader := bytes.NewReader(eBytes)
    var e uint64
    err = binary.Read(eReader, binary.BigEndian, &e)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    pKey := rsa.PublicKey{N: n, E: int(e)}
    w := strings.SplitAfter(auth_token, ".")    
    for i, val := range w {
        w[i] = strings.Trim(val, ".")
    }
    y := w[0:2]

    //Join just the first two parts, the header and the payload without the signature
    o := strings.Join(y, ".")   
    headerOauth := DecodeB64(nil,[]byte(w[0]),e64)
    inblockOauth := DecodeB64(nil,[]byte(w[1]),e64)
    toHash := string(headerOauth) + "}." + string(inblockOauth)
    digestOauth := DecodeB64(nil, []byte(w[2]),e64)

    hasherOauth := sha256.New()
    hasherOauth.Write([]byte(toHash))

    // validation here fails
    err = rsa.VerifyPKCS1v15(&pKey,crypto.SHA256,hasherOauth.Sum(nil),digestOauth)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error verifying key %s",err.Error())
        return err
    }
    return err
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**
Here is toHash var which contains header and payload:

```
{"alg":"RS256","kid":"d91c503452d0f8849200a321ffbf7dea76f9371d"}.{"iss":"accounts.google.com","sub":"104869993929250743503","azp":"client_email_till_@.apps.googleusercontent.com","email":"test@test.hr","at_hash":"KAm1M0g-ssMkdjds7jkbVQ","email_verified":true,"aud":client_email_till_@.apps.googleusercontent.com","hd":"test.hr","iat":1412246551,"exp":1412250451}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Thanks for the reply @Florent Morselli, I tried it again and it failed, I B64decoded this time only the third part (signature) but the error was still there, could someone test it with their
auth_token, just put the ID token in auth_token variable below in the code, and let me know if it worked, thank You.

```
package main
import(
    "strings"
    "encoding/binary"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "encoding/base64"
    "io/ioutil"
    "crypto"    
    "crypto/sha256"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "math/big"  

)

func main() {
    auth_token := ""
    w := strings.SplitAfter(auth_token, ".")    
    for i, val := range w {
        w[i] = strings.Trim(val, ".")
    }
    headerOauth, err := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(w[0])

    res, err := http.Get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/certs")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    certs, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    //extract kid from token header
    var header interface{}

    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(string(headerOauth)+"}"), &header)

    token_kid := header.(map[string]interface{})["kid"]
    fmt.Println("By 1")
    //get modulus and exponent from the cert

    var goCertificate interface{}

    err = json.Unmarshal(certs, &goCertificate)    

    //k := goCertificate.(map[string]interface{})[token_kid.(string)]
    k := goCertificate.(map[string]interface{})["keys"]

    ///*mod & exp part
    j := k.([]interface{})
    x := j[0]

    if j[0].(map[string]interface{})["kid"] == token_kid {
        x = j[0]
    }else{
        if j[1].(map[string]interface{})["kid"] == token_kid {
            x = j[1]
        }else{
            errors.New("Token is not valid, kid from token and certificate don't match")

        }
    }
    h := x.(map[string]interface{})["n"]
    g := x.(map[string]interface{})["e"]

    //build the google pub key
    nStr := h.(string)
    decN, err := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(nStr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    n := big.NewInt(0)
    n.SetBytes(decN)
    eStr := g.(string)
    decE, err := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(eStr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    var eBytes []byte
    if len(decE) < 8 {
        eBytes = make([]byte, 8-len(decE), 8)
        eBytes = append(eBytes, decE...)
    } else {
        eBytes = decE
    }

    eReader := bytes.NewReader(eBytes)
    var e uint64
    err = binary.Read(eReader, binary.BigEndian, &e)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    pKey := rsa.PublicKey{N: n, E: int(e)}
        //inblockOauth := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(w[1])
    toHash := w[0] + "." + w[1]
    digestOauth, err := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(w[2])

    hasherOauth := sha256.New()
    hasherOauth.Write([]byte(toHash))

    // verification here fails
    err = rsa.VerifyPKCS1v15(&pKey,crypto.SHA256,hasherOauth.Sum(nil),digestOauth)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error verifying key %s",err.Error())

    }

}
```

Comment: @RickyA - crypto/rsa: verification error

Comment: do you have a test auth_token to test with?

Comment: @RickyA - I have update my question (I've put  toHash variable content on the end of the question)

Comment: @RickyA - this is just for structure purpose so I changed details, I can send you token over mail test auth_token (I'll create test gmail account and send you)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained on the chat, the problem is that the Base64 decoder is unable to decode the header and the signature if they are missing "=".

You just have to add them with the following code:

```
    if m := len(h_) % 4; m != 0 {
        h_ += strings.Repeat("=", 4-m)
    }
```

Here is the complete code:

```
package main
import(
    "strings"
    "encoding/binary"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "encoding/base64"
    "io/ioutil"
    "crypto"    
    "crypto/sha256"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "math/big"  

)

func main() {
    auth_token := ""
    w := strings.Split(auth_token, ".")    
    h_, s_ := w[0], w[2]

    if m := len(h_) % 4; m != 0 {
        h_ += strings.Repeat("=", 4-m)
    }
    if m := len(s_) % 4; m != 0 {
        s_ += strings.Repeat("=", 4-m)
    }

    headerOauth, err := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(h_)

    res, err := http.Get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/certs")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    certs, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    //extract kid from token header
    var header interface{}

    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(string(headerOauth)), &header)

    token_kid := header.(map[string]interface{})["kid"]
    fmt.Println("By 1")
    //get modulus and exponent from the cert

    var goCertificate interface{}

    err = json.Unmarshal(certs, &goCertificate)    

    //k := goCertificate.(map[string]interface{})[token_kid.(string)]
    k := goCertificate.(map[string]interface{})["keys"]

    ///*mod & exp part
    j := k.([]interface{})
    x := j[0]

    if j[0].(map[string]interface{})["kid"] == token_kid {
        x = j[0]
    }else{
        if j[1].(map[string]interface{})["kid"] == token_kid {
            x = j[1]
        }else{
            errors.New("Token is not valid, kid from token and certificate don't match")

        }
    }
    h := x.(map[string]interface{})["n"]
    g := x.(map[string]interface{})["e"]

    //build the google pub key
    nStr := h.(string)
    decN, err := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(nStr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    n := big.NewInt(0)
    n.SetBytes(decN)
    eStr := g.(string)
    decE, err := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(eStr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    var eBytes []byte
    if len(decE) < 8 {
        eBytes = make([]byte, 8-len(decE), 8)
        eBytes = append(eBytes, decE...)
    } else {
        eBytes = decE
    }

    eReader := bytes.NewReader(eBytes)
    var e uint64
    err = binary.Read(eReader, binary.BigEndian, &e)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    pKey := rsa.PublicKey{N: n, E: int(e)}
        //inblockOauth := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(w[1])
    toHash := w[0] + "." + w[1]
    digestOauth, err := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(s_)

    hasherOauth := sha256.New()
    hasherOauth.Write([]byte(toHash))

    // verification of the signature
    err = rsa.VerifyPKCS1v15(&pKey,crypto.SHA256,hasherOauth.Sum(nil),digestOauth)


    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error verifying key %s",err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("OK!")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the StdEncoding, it is not URL-Safe as required by the specification.

Use **URLEncoding** instead. See https://gobyexample.com/base64-encoding for more informations.

The Base64 Url Safe is the same as Base64 but does not contain '/' and '+' (replaced by '_' and '-') and trailing '=' are removed.

Comment: thank you for your answer, that is correct but it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

`I send the **decoded** header.payload together with the Google pKey + digest to the rsa function rsa.VerifyPKCS1v15.`

You are wrong in this part. You must send to the RSA function `rsa.VerifyPKCS1v15` the **encoded** header.payload

In another words: you checked the signature of `{"alg":"RS256","kid":"d91c503452d0f8849200a321ffbf7dea76f9371d"}.{"iss":"accounts.google.com","sub":"104869993929250743503","azp":"client_email_till_@.apps.googleusercontent.com","email":"test@test.hr","at_hash":"KAm1M0g-ssMkdjds7jkbVQ","email_verified":true,"aud":client_email_till_@.apps.googleusercontent.com","hd":"test.hr","iat":1412246551,"exp":1412250451}` **which is wrong**.

You must check the signature of `eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImQ5MWM1MDM0NTJkMGY4ODQ5MjAwYTMyMWZmYmY3ZGVhNzZmOTM3MWQifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiMTA0ODY5OTkzOTI5MjUwNzQzNTAzIiwiYXpwIjoiY2xpZW50X2VtYWlsX3RpbGxfQC5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdEB0ZXN0LmhyIiwiYXRfaGFzaCI6IktBbTFNMGctc3NNa2RqZHM3amtiVlEiLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiYXVkIjpjbGllbnRfZW1haWxfdGlsbF9ALmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiaGQiOiJ0ZXN0LmhyIiwiaWF0IjoxNDEyMjQ2NTUxLCJleHAiOjE0MTIyNTA0NTF9`.

Comment: I've tried your method but without success, I've put update in my question with code example (UPDATE 2)

Comment: Please can you send me the complete JWS you want to test?

Comment: do you want over email or?

Comment: I've sent you token over contact form you gave me

Comment: I received your JWS. Thank you. I tried to verify it using my PHP lib and it failed too. I do not think that your code is wrong, it seems that the signature of your token is bad. Can you try to generate a new one?

Comment: When I paste my token to google endpoint "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=" it decodes it as correct, no errors are returned, so I think the token is correct, maybe it's something wrong with the splitting of the token in my code, or it has to do something with the public key from google certs

Comment: I was wrong, your JWS are valid (copy/paste error, I am sorry for that). I am still investigating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62776/discussion-between-florent-morselli-and-croios).

Answer (score 1):

The input to be checked should be the $base64_header.$base64_claim_set.
From [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount):

> JSON Web Signature (JWS) is the specification that guides the
>   mechanics of generating the signature for the JWT. The input for the
>   signature is the byte array of the following content: 
>   `{Base64url encoded header}.{Base64url encoded claim set}`

I think you probably just hardcoded the cert index for demonstrating. In your real code, you should choose the correct cert based on the "kid" field in the header.

Comment: You're right, I have hardcoded the index, i made it depend on "kid" from the token in the meantime. I validated my token on https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token= , and it's ok, I hardcoded the header.payload (both are b64 encoded) and signature (b64 decoded) and send it to the VerifyPKCS1v15 and it threw the same error. I suspect I haven't derived the google oauth public key on a right way maybe.

Comment: `Printf("Pub key: %v", &pKey) returns this:  &{79385446464729122523482302355457174565335860319326282821160915491 65537}`
Is this the right format? Thanks