# Google SignIn validation error using jwt-go

Tags: go, google-signin, jwt-go

I'm currently trying to integrate my app with Google SignIn. I want my Golang backend to be able to decode and validate OIDC tokens. I'm trying to use the [JWT-GO library](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/), but I'm stuck with the validation of the signature of the JWT.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159658/golang-token-validation-error/26287613#26287613) and it helped me well, still I can't figure out why I'm getting an `crypto/rsa: verification error`.

I pushed an example code in this [Github repository](https://github.com/aubm/golang-google-sign-in). Would be great if someone could help with that.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why are you not using OAuth2? Like in [this example](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-go) ?

Comment: Hey :) from what I see, this example you mentioned doesn't seem to cover the implicit flow in which you need to validate the signature of the token on the server side. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the library only seems to support the authorization code grant type.

Comment: I have not sorted how the n and e are encoded, but the DecodeString of n is returning an err: "Error illegal base64 data at input byte 340".  Having a dickens of a time finding a description of the n and e fields from the document.  I think you are very close if we crack how those ints are encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work, more details here : https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/issues/116#issuecomment-188903951